# How to join entity by id

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Could you help me solve a small question?
It's about the project with Spring Data, JPA and Hibernate.

I have 2 entities and I need to join one to another. Yes, it sounds simple :)

First is Activity:

```
public class Activity {
  ...

  @Column(name="STATUS_ID")
  private String statusId;

  ...
}
```

Second is Vocab Value (Users can administer it as a simple list of values):

```
public class VocabValue {
  ...

  // Type of vocab (in our case - 'ACT_STAT')
  @Column(name="TYPE")
  private String type;

  // Name - code of Vocab value
  @Column(name="NAME")
  private String type;

  // Value
  @Column(name="VAL")
  private String value;

  ...
}
```

In my case, I want to store in an Activity a name of Vocab Value and join it.

In the target state, my entity should look like:

```
public class Activity {
  ...

  @Column(name="STATUS_ID")
  private String statusId;

  @... what?
  private String status;

  // Getter returns Vocab Value in accordance with the following join spec (pseudo-sql):
  // select voc.value from VocabValue voc where voc.name = %statusId% and type = 'ACT_STAT'
  public String getStatus() {
  }

  ...
}
```

How should I configure my Activity entity to provide this?
Ok, Is it possible?

I'll be grateful for your advice!

Thank!

**Update 13.01**

I've tried this solution:

```
public class Activity {

  ...
  @Column(name="STATUS_ID")
  private String statusId;

  @JoinColumn(name = "STATUS_ID", referencedColumnName = "NAME",   insertable = false, updatable = false)
  @Where(clause = "type = 'ACT_STAT'")
  @ManyToOne(optional = true)
  @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
  private VocabValue status;

  ...
}
```

Moreover, I had to make VocabValue implementation of Serializable (VocabValue as Detached entity should be implemetation of Serializable interface in accordance with Hibernate spec).

```
public VocabValue implemets Serializable {...}
```

It works, but annotation @Where doesn't work: Join performed only with @JoinColumn specification, an additional criteria, defined in @Where clause doesn't apply.

Whether there are workarounds?

**UPDATE 13.01 - 2**

It was solved with following configuration:

```
@JoinFormula(value="SELECT v.ROW_ID FROM VOCAB v WHERE v.NAME=STATUS_ID AND v.TYPE='ACT_STAT'") 
@ManyToOne 
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE) 
private VocabValue status;
```

Thanks!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved with following configuration:

```
@JoinFormula(value="SELECT v.ROW_ID FROM VOCAB v WHERE v.NAME=STATUS_ID AND v.TYPE='ACT_STAT'") 
@ManyToOne 
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE) 
private VocabValue status;
```

Thank's )